# Recovering corrupted superblocks in live USB

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning, systemd

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on an external USB drive. Recently, the file system and all superblock backups got corrupted after recklessly unplugging them from an old desktop PC. I tried using `fsck` and `fdisk` to recover from the backup superblocks and correct sectors, but unfortunately, neither helped. I could open it from a live USB, but after opening the bootable partition, I changed the ownership of the files in order to transfer them to another disk. I don't know if this may affect the situation, but it doesn't boot and gives the following errors while booting.

[image]

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 4965840/30220288 files, 101135365/120875244 blocks
[   9.870902] systemd[1]: networking-routes.service: Job networking-routes.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
[   9.907296] systemd[1]: Failed to start Uncomplicated firewall.
[FAILED] Failed to start Uncomplicated firewall.
See 'systemctl status ufw.service' for details.
[   9.908207] systemd[1]: Failed to start Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[FAILED] Failed to start Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel
See 'systemctl status kmode-static-nodes.service' for details.
[   9.908718] systemd[1]: Failed to mount POSIX Message Queue File System.
[FAILED] Failed to mount POSIX Message Queue File System.
See 'systemctl status dev-mqueue.mount' for details.
[   9.909226] systemd[1]: Failed to start Set console keymap.
[FAILED] Failed to start Set console keymap.
See 'systemctl status keyboard-setup.service' for details.
[   9.909634] systemd[1]: Failed to mount Debug File System.
[FAILED] Failed to mount Debug File System.
See 'systemctl status sys-kernel-debug.mount' for details.
[   9.910156] systemd[1]: Failed to mount Huge Pages File System.
[FAILED] Failed to mount Huge Pages File System.
See 'systemctl status dev-hugepages.mount' for details.
[ OK ] Started Load Kernel Modules.
[ OK ] Started Journal Service.
       Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
       Mounting FUSE Control File System...
       Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[FAILED] Failed to mount Fuse Control File System.  
See 'systemctl status sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount' for details.   
[FAILED] Failed to start Static Device Nodes in /dev.   
See 'systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service' for details.  
[ OK ] Started Apply Kernel Variables.
       Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[ OK ] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
       Starting LSB: QEMU KVM module loading script...
       Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: QEMU KVM module loading script.   
See 'systemctl status qemu-kvm.service' for details.    
[FAILED] Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.  
See 'systemctl status systemd-remount-fs.service' for details.
       Activating swap /swapfile...
       Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[ OK ] Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
       Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
       Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[FAILED] Failed to start udev Coldplug all Devices. 
See 'systemctl status systemd.udev-trigger.service' for details.    
[FAILED] Failed to start Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.   
See 'systemctl status systemd-journal-flush.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
See 'Systemctl status swapfile.swap' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
[ OK ] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
       Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
```

[Dmesg Output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0fcv5jxb8u1l2e/dmesgOutput.txt?dl=0)

fdisk Output

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1c297f28

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048 967004001 967001954 461.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       967004160 976773119   9768960   4.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

I can post other details when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often easier and faster to re-install the system than to try to repair the system, but if there are important data without backup you have no choice.

Can you read your personal files, when the computer is booted from another drive? In that case I suggest that you save all those files to another drive. You might try to backup the whole home directory (from the system in the drive with corrupted superblocks).

If you cannot read your personal files, and the data are very valuable, I suggest that you clone the drive with ***ddrescue*** and do the repair/recovery work on the cloned copy to avoid causing more damage to the file system. Otherwise you can work directly on the drive itself.

I would start with ***e2fsck*** and try to repair the file system, and I noticed that you tried it already. Which options did you use?

***Testdisk*** and ***PhotoRec*** are two tools that you can try if *e2fsck* could not fix it. Testdisk can repair file systems, that are 'not too damaged'. PhotoRec can recover files even when the file system is damaged beyond repair, as long as the data cells on the disk are not overwritten.

You find details at the following link and links from it.

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

And you are welcome to ask, if you need more help :-)

Comment: I did exactly what you told without reading what you wrote. As i said above, all the super block entries were corrupted and e2fsck could not solve the issue with -n -v -b options. So I had to copy the file system and reinstalled it. In fact, i downloaded Testdisk and PhotoRec but,  i did not try them out enough

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution to get a working system again. It is even better that you found it yourself, than that you followed my "cook-book" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing `casper/initrd.lz` on the USB from the original ISO file.